# ASP.Net label control re-appears after JQuery .hide() method call

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following jquery code to hide an asp.net label control on an asp.net button click event. The code hides the label but the label appears again after next moment. I don't have any server-side code yet for the button. Here is the jquery:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= btnTest.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $("#<%= lblTest.ClientID %>").css('display','none'); //i also tried .hide()
        });

    });

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Is there any suggestion for me?

Comment: Is the button inside an `UpdatePanel`? It sounds like the HTML is being refreshed when the button is clicked so your hide gets undone.

Comment: yes, if you use `..function(e)..` and place a `e.preventDefault()` inside the callback, you should avoid the problem commented above

Comment: No, it's not in update panel. There is no update panel on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your Page is getting postback.
When you click the button first the javascript method gets executed and then the the page get postbacks. This can happen even if you haven't written any Server side handler for that button.

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= btnTest.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $("#<%= lblTest.ClientID %>").css('display','none'); //i also tried .hide()
            return false;
        });

    });
```